# Como faço para criar um evento no momento que alguém digitar algo no EditText?

Tags: java, android, edittext

Gostaria de criar um evento conforme o usuário vai digitando alguma palavra no meu `EditText`, porém não sei como acessá-lo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar o `addTextChangedListener()`. Veja o código abaixo:

```
seuEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { 
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 

// Aqui você coloca o evento

} 
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
} 
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
} 
});
```

Veja mais detalhes [na documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)).

Comment: Excelente, era isso mesmo que eu estava precisando. Obrigado.